# How to attach created .pdf to email body with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a converted document from .docx into .pdf saved to the desktop. The last task is to attach this .pdf to the body of an e-mail; the HTML signature should remain unchanged.

I think the problem is this line of code and I don't know how to correct it:

```
.Attachments.Add PdfFile.FullName
```

The complete code:

```
Public Sub Mail()
    Dim LastAuthor As String
        LastAuthor = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("last Author")

        Dim Email As String
            Email = Replace(LastAuthor, " ", ".") & "@xyz.ro"


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .Signature = "HTMLbody"
        .To = Email
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ActiveDocument.Name
        '.Body = "AVIZAT. Multumesc mult"
        '.Attachments.Add ActiveDocument.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the mail.
        .HTMLbody = "AVIZAT, esantionul este in ordine. Multumesc" & "<br>" & .HTMLbody

        Dim objDoc As Document
        Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
        objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=Replace(objDoc.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf"), _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent
        ' Add the attachment first for correct attachment's name with non English symbols
        .Attachments.Add PdfFile.FullName
        '.Preview 'Preview the email must disable .send & MsgBox (or use .Send to send it)
        .send
        MsgBox "E-mail trimis cu succes"

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
Public Sub Mail()

    Dim LastAuthor As String
    Dim Email As String
    Dim MyPdfName As String
    Dim objDoc As Document

    LastAuthor = ActiveDocument.BuiltinDocumentProperties("last Author")
    Email = Replace(LastAuthor, " ", ".") & "@xyz.ro"

    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    MyPdfName = Replace(objDoc.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf")
    objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    OutputFileName:=MyPdfName, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
    Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = Email
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = objDoc.Name
        .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri>Servus<br>Esantionul este in ordine.<br><br>Multumesc,<br>" & .HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add MyPdfName
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "E-mail trimis cu succes"

End Sub
```

It's far from perfect but is a lot clearer now and most importantly, works.

Comment: Hi, Daniel, I have an Error 438 on line .Signature="HTML Body" Object doesn't support property or method. Please help!

Comment: I found the solution if I erase the line .Signature="HTML Body". And, yes, now is allot clearer and cleaner:) Thank you very much, Daniel!

Comment: one last question: if I want this text to be on three lines, one on top of another? From this :"Buna ziua. AVIZAT, esantionul este in ordine. Multumesc" & "<br>" & .HTMLBody                                                                                                         
To this:    Buna ziua,/on first line;                                                                                      
               AVIZAT, esantionul este in ordine./second line;                                                
               Multumesc/third line

Comment: I managed to write the line, but the text doesn't have same Font and Font size, the text in first row is different from the next two lines. Code line: .HTMLBody = "Servus," & "<br>" & "Esantionul este in ordine." & "<br><br>" & "Multumesc," & "<br>" & .HTMLBody

Comment: Sorry I missed the ".Signature = "HTMLbody" godd thing you removed it. Note in your body string add " & .HTMLbody" - this will add existing body to your body (so your default signature).

Comment: To change font, size etc you can add "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Calibri>" (or whatever settings are suitable) in your string; I have edited my original response to reflect that. I've also changed your subject from "activedocument.name" to "objDoc.Name" as this is much better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable advice, Daniel! Job done!